# Count of posts by different parameters?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-meta

I need to get the count of posts (just a number, nothing else) by `custom taxonomy` AND `post meta(string)` but I can't find a good way to combine them both.

Im fairly new to programming & WP, Im not sure where to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WP_Query` with a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and a [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) argument, and return only IDs to save a bit of server resource.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'people',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'bob',
    ),
  ),
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'age',
      'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
      'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
  ),
  'fields' => 'ids'.
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And check the `found_posts` element of `$query`-- `var_dump($query->found_posts);`

Comment: Thank you! It's worked out perfectly. Is there a way to get the count of different taxonomies with one request? I mean different numbers, not combined.

Comment: No. There is no core function to do that.